# Joda time openapi generation does not generated properly

Tags: pom.xml, jodatime, codegen

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I generate code via open-api and it generated like the following; but it can not be resolved.
I tried to update the time dependency as above but it didnt help that much.

I need to **org.joda.time.*** to be resolved as **org.joda.time.LocalDate**

How could I provide that and the resolving works as expected?

```
  @JsonProperty("localTime")
  private org.joda.time.* localTime;
```